# ng-click in footable responsive cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, footable

I am using footable for responsive table in Mobile devices.
In following code my ng-click when click on count function call works perfect in desktop,But in mobile cell ng-click doesn't work.

```html
    
<div class="footable-row-detail-row"><div class="footable-row-detail-name">Total Counts:</div><div class="footable-row-detail-value"><span class="table-select"><a class="link-yellow ng-binding" ng-click="getUsers(records.id);">2</a></span></div></div>
```

Comment: Hi, use ngTouch for mobile device [ngTouch](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngTouch)

Comment: And read this too [ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch)

Comment: for enable ngClick  for touch-enabled devices, you have to inject ngTouch in your app, the ngTouch based on jQuery Mobile touch event handling.